# When to rearm epoll with edge mode & oneshot?

Tags: c, linux, epoll

I'm writing a coroutine wrapper for sockets as a demo for coroutine use cases and I'm struggling a bit with how to use epoll safely (without introducing race conditions).

I have already figured out that I have to use the edge mode `EPOLLET` with `EPOLLONESHOT`. But now I'm not sure when I should be rearming the socket.

Should I rearm before calling a non-blocking operation or after? I want to make sure that I neither miss the event nor receive a phantom one.

```
// epoll & socket setup

int ret;

ret = epoll_ctl(epoll_, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, ...); // rearm here
//...
ret = read(...);
//...
ret = epoll_ctl(epoll_, EPOL_CTL_MOD, ...); // or here?

int ret = epoll_wait(...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I rearm before calling a non-blocking operation or after?

Technically, after, but it's not as simple as that.

Regardless of `EPOLLONESHOT`, once you receive an edge-triggered event signalling read-readiness of a given file descriptor, you must consider that FD to continue to be ready until a `read()` on it fails with `errno` set to `EAGAIN` (and therefore the file must be in non-blocking mode).  Over the course of those reads, it may be the case that you read all remaining bytes with one `read()`, but then more arrive before the next.  In that case, if the FD is still armed then a new event for it will be queued (or merged with another event for that FD, as appropriate).  This is the case that could result in you receiving an event when in fact the FD is not any longer ready.

You should consider just accepting those "phantom" events.  Since your file will be in non-blocking mode, they will not cause unwanted stalls, just a little extra work.  And your code will be simpler. But if you do use `EPOLLONESHOT` to avoid receiving phantom events, then you must not re-arm the FD before you determine it to be unready (via a `read` failing with `EAGAIN`), else you defeat the purpose.

Thus, the full answer is ***after the FD is determined to be unready***.  That will take at least two `read()`s, and possibly more.  If the file becomes ready after the last read and before the rearming then the rearming should cause an appropriate event to be queued.

Comment: OK, just a small clarification. Am I guaranteed to receive the event if I rearm after? Or is there a chance that I will miss it?

Comment: @ŠimonTóth, my understanding is that if the FD is already ready when you rearm, then an event with be triggered immediately.  The documentation is not very clear on that, but epoll would otherwise be very broken.

Comment: But again, do consider just not using `EPOLLONESHOT`.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation sucks, that's why I posted the question. I will just go and trust this interpretation and will indeed just do `EPOLLET` without `EPOLLONESHOT`.